# Force a step in a function to happen only after ajax call has been completeed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to pause the rest of a function when you are waiting for a value to be returned from an asynchronous call with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this "paused" behavior, you want to put the behavior inside the promise object.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   data: myData
}).success(function() {
  //put your code here this will only fire after it returns successfully
}).error(function() {
  //This will fire if there is an error 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example. I want to give you and the other answerer + rep, but I'm not able to do so at this time.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about would be a synchronous call, which is not recommended as it will freeze the UI.

Instead, use the callback provided in the jQuery call to perform the rest of your code:

```
function DoSomeCall()
{
    $.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
      //Do your follow on code in here, in the callback.
    });

    //Don't do any code here that relies on the AJAX being finished first.
}
```

Comment: I actually did try something like that and my screen froze for awhile. It worked, but my users will definitely not like the black screen and other oddities associated with it :(   
Since I have a number of functions which need to access a variable that I can only get with an asynchronous call, I was hoping there was a way to separate way to do this. But thank you very much for the explanations!

Comment: This shouldn't cause your screen to freeze, it should be asynchronous and not really be doing anything while it is waiting.  Are you sure it is this and not your follow on code that is causing the freezing?

Comment: Sorry, I was saying that making the synchronous call froze the UI.